# How to append output to an existing file in pipeline code

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a file called `Sample.txt`, now I want to append an Output value to this file.

I tried with the following command, but it is overwriting the file.

```
writeFile file: "sample.txt", text: "$projectVersion"
```

How can I achieve it.

Comment: Read the file first and combine it with `$projectVersion`?

Comment: Thanks, got it .

Comment: Then please post the result here as an answer so that others having the same problem can benefit from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved

```java
def readContent = readFile "sample.txt"
writeFile file: "sample.txt", text: "$readContent Version=$projectVersion\n"
echo "${sample.txt}"
```

Comment: thanks for posting. the last line reads weird.. probably you've wrapped that in an `sh` step?

Comment: What happens if the file does not exist before line 1?